# If the asteroid that wiped out most of the dinosaurs had impacted much closer to the poles, would the extinction event have be smaller?

Tags: geology, paleontology, mass-extinction, asteroids

The case is that, if it landed at the North Pole or the South Pole, the global after-impact effects such as gases and dust spreading through the atmosphere, earthquakes, tsunamis, volcanism and massive forest fires would be minimized, could become more regional.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the results to be much less destructive except that the Chicxulub impact hit carbonate rock, that made a lot of acid rain and made a lot of atmospheric CO2, so perhaps less global warming after global cooling, ie after the aerosols settled and rained out. The fires were global from the planet being circled with hot ejecta, that both rained down and radiated heat down. https://www.lpi.usra.edu/science/kring/Chicxulub/